Como implementar una clase que ejecute un metodo de procesamiento de imagen
espero estén bien, tengo un problema con mi codigo, estoy intentanto hacer un metodo generico que me implemente el procesamiento de imagen con opencv. El siguiente archivo si funciona correctamente.

window_1.py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt6 import uic   
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLabel, QApplication, QWidget

from Views.Utils.video_capture import VideoCaptureThread
# from Views.Utils.image_processing import ImageProcessing

class Window_One(QWidget):
# Constructor 
def __init__(self):
    super(Window_One, self).__init__()

    # Calling Draw components
    self.draw_components()

    self.start_video_capture()

# Draw components
def draw_components(self):
    # Load template
    uic.loadUi('Views/templates/window_one.ui', self)

     # Components
    self.lbl_camera = self.findChild(QLabel, 'lbl_camera')

    self.start_camera = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'start_camera')

    self.stop_camera = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'stop_camera')

    self.close_window = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'close_window')

def start_video_capture(self):
    # Create Video Capture Instance
    self.video_capture_instance = VideoCaptureThread()
    # Connect to update image
    self.video_capture_instance.changePixmapSignal.connect(self.update_Image)
    # Start thread
    self.video_capture_instance.start()

@pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
def update_Image(self, cv_img):
    self.lbl_camera.setScaledContents(True)
    self.imageResult = self.convert_cv2Image_to_qt_image(cv_img)
    self.lbl_camera.setPixmap(self.imageResult)

def convert_cv2Image_to_qt_image(self, cv_img) -> QPixmap:
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
    btyes_per_line = ch * w

    q_image = QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, btyes_per_line, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
    pixmap_image = QPixmap.fromImage(q_image)
    return pixmap_image

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window_One()

sys.exit(app.exec())

Lo que quiero hacer es meter los metodos start_video_capture, update_Image y convert_cv2Image_to_qt_image en una clase y pasar por constructor la QLabel donde se proyectara la imagen.
Algo como lo siguiente

image_processing.py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, QObject
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from . video_capture import VideoCaptureThread

class ImageProcessing(QObject):
# Constructor
def __init__(self, lbl_screen=None):
    super(ImageProcessing, self).__init__()
    
    # Properties
    self.lbl_camera = lbl_screen

def start_video_capture(self):
    # Create Video Capture Instance
    self.video_capture_instance = VideoCaptureThread()
    # Connect to update image
    self.video_capture_instance.changePixmapSignal.connect(self.update_Image)
    # Start thread
    self.video_capture_instance.start()

@pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
def update_Image(self, cv_img):
    self.lbl_camera.setScaledContents(True)
    self.imageResult = self.convert_cv2Image_to_qt_image(cv_img)
    self.lbl_camera.setPixmap(self.imageResult)

def convert_cv2Image_to_qt_image(self, cv_img) -> QPixmap:
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
    btyes_per_line = ch * w

    q_image = QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, btyes_per_line, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
    pixmap_image = QPixmap.fromImage(q_image)
    return pixmap_image


if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

instance = ImageProcessing()

sys.exit(app.exec())

Si ejecuto el archivo ImageProcessing por si solo si funciona, pero si creo una instancia me aparece el siguiente error

QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

De aqui obtengo la captura de la camara
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class VideoCaptureThread(QThread):
changePixmapSignal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
runs = True

def stop(self):
    self.quit()
    self.wait()

def run(self):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)

    while True:
        ret, cv_img = cap.read()
        if ret:
            self.changePixmapSignal.emit(cv_img)


Ese error suele ser causado por destruir la instancia QThread de Python mientras el hilo de Qt sigue ejecutandose ¿Estás destruyendo o dejando sin referencia (será recolectada por el GC) tu instancia de ImageProcessing en algún momento? Por ejemplo, si en un método o función  asignas a una variable local tu instancia de  ImageProcessing, cuando el método retorne la variable saldrá de ámbito, la instancia de  ImageProcessing quedará sin referenicas, el GC la recolectará y con ella la instancia de QThread asociada a su atributo video_capture_instance

Si es este el caso, o evitas la destruccion del objeto o detienes el hilo antes, dependiendo de como lo este usando. Cuando ejecutas el script directamente la instanicia se asigna a una variable global, no será destruida durante la vida entera del programa. ¿Podrías agregar como estás usando la clase cuando el error tiene lugar?

Bueno, al final solo tuve heredar la clase de la siguiente manera class ImageProcessing(VideoCaptureThread): con eso funciono para que ya no se cerrara la app.

Claro, al hacer eso obviamente mantienes la referencia al QThread mientras la instancia de ImageProcessing exista ya que es ella misma el QThread :).
